# Mobile SDK Functionality

Tags: android, ios, paypal

I would like to use the Paypal's Mobile SDK in my Mobile App. Would anyone be able to tell me if the Mobile SDK can do the following things:

1) Transfer money between two PayPal accounts.

2) Make a payment to a PayPal account using credit or debit card details.

3) Register a new PayPal account.

4) Save PayPal details for future use without having to log in again.

5) Save Credit card details for future use without having to log in again.

suggest me above.

Answer (score 0):

Specific answers to your questions are below, but I'd encourage you to check out the [Braintree v.zero SDK](https://www.braintreepayments.com/) as it contains the PayPal MSDK for PayPal, but has many more payment options including credit card tokenization. (Braintree is owned by PayPal.)

1. The MSDK can allow accept money from the user's PayPal account into your merchant PayPal account, but does not allow you to move money between arbitrary accounts.
2. The MSDK allows you to accept credit cards into your merchant PayPal account.
3. The MSDK login page provides a link to a mobile friendly web page that permits new users to sign up.
4. Yes.
5. No.